# How to shift right div towards the left when left div is empty on run time?

Tags: php, html, css, runtime

I have mention my question in the problem statement.

I am working on a website in which I want to shift a right div towards the left **when left div is empty on run time**.

Here **left div** is `<div class="pickup-from-items-location">` and **right div** 
is `<div class="deliver-to-my-location">`.

`<div class="timings">` is the child div for **both of the left and right div**.

The code which has **left and right divs are**:

```
<div class="received">
   <div class="pickup-from-items-location">
      <div class="timings">
         <?php 
            echo $data['item'];

              $serialized = '';
              for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->item_logistic); $i++) {
              if(strcmp($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_type, "location_pickup") == 0)
              {
              $serialized .= strtolower($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_times);
              }
              }
              if($serialized != '')
              {
              echo
              '<div class="icons_text"> 
              <img src="/images/rsz_venueorange__1_.png"> 
              <p class="mt-4 mb-3 heading_size">pickup from item\'s location </p>
              </div>'; 
              /*
              echo '<span class="font-weight-bold how-can-this-text">' . "how can this item be received" . '</span>';
              echo "<br>"; 
              echo "<br>"; 
              echo '<span class="font-weight-bold mb-3 ml-3">' . "pickup from item's location <br/>" . '</span>';
              echo "<br>";
              echo "<br>"; */
              $unserialized = unserialize( $serialized );


              foreach($unserialized as $key=>$value) 
              {
              echo '
              <div class="dates_timings_items_availability"> 
              <div class="items_availability_weekdays">'. strtolower(date('l', strtotime($key))) .':</div>
              <div class="items_availability_time"><span>'. $value['start'] .'</span></div>
              <div class="delimiter">to</div>
              <div class="items_availability_time"><span>'. $value['end'] .'</span></div>
              </div>'; 
              } 
              }


              else
              {
              /* echo "<p style=\"font-style: italic;\">No information available</p>"; */ 
              }
              ?>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- how can this item be received + PICKUP from item's location (FINISH) -->
   <!--DELIVER to my location (START)-->
   <div class="deliver-to-my-location">
      <div class="timings">
         <?php
            $serialized = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->item_logistic); $i++) {
            if(strcmp($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_type, "delivery") == 0)
            {
            $serialized .= strtolower($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_times);
            }
            }
            if($serialized != '')
            {
            echo 
            '<div class="icons_text"> 
            <img src="/images/rsz_deliveryicon__1_.png"> 
            <p class="mt-4 heading_size mb-3" style="width:100%;">deliver to my location </p>
            </div>'; 
            /*
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo '<span class="font-weight-bold mb-3 ml-3">' . "deliver to my location <br/>" . '</span>';
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>"; */
            $unserialized = unserialize( $serialized );

            foreach($unserialized as $key=>$value) {
            echo '
            <div class="dates_timings_items_availability"> 
            <div class="items_availability_weekdays">'. strtolower(date('l', strtotime($key))) .':</div>
            <div class="items_availability_time"><span>'. date('g:i a', strtotime($value['start'])) .'</span></div>
            <div class="delimiter">to</div>
            <div class="items_availability_time"><span>'. date('g:i a', strtotime($value['end'])) .'</span></div>
            </div>';
            }
            }

            ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code for the above is:

```
.received 
{
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.pickup-from-items-location 
{
margin-right: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.deliver-to-my-location 
{
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

**Problem  Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **css code above or JS/Jquery code I need to add** so that **when left div is empty on run time**, right div should move towards the left.

The **left div becomes empty at run time as I am using a php code above**.

so `<div class="pickup-from-items-location"> <div class="timings">` becomes empty when $serialized string is null because I am using `if($serialized != '')` condition above.

```
          [[LEFT]                                              [RIGHT]]
```

Left Div is  `<div class="pickup-from-items-location">` and Right Div is `<div class="deliver-to-my-location">`

so when **Left Div is empty, Right Div should move towards the left**.

```
          [[RIGHT]]
```

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for, it is an dummy example - https://jsfiddle.net/bkec09ha/21/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Serg's answer above, I think you misunderstood his answer. I completely agree with it. Essentially your current code is always displaying the two `<div>`'s but you wanted to hide the already displayed `<div>` if there was no content. That doesn't make much sense and you could easily block out that step. Instead let your PHP script determine that there is no content and set the `if` statement outside of the `<div>` so that it only displays when there is content (as specified by `if($serialized != '')`). I've applied that change to my code below, please try it.

```
<div class="received">
  <?php
    $serialized = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->item_logistic); $i++) {
        if (strcmp($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_type, "location_pickup") == 0) {
            $serialized .= strtolower($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_times);
        }
    }
    if ($serialized != '') {
  ?>
   <div class="pickup-from-items-location">
      <div class="timings">
        <?php
          echo $data['item'];

          echo '<div class="icons_text">
                    <img src="/images/rsz_venueorange__1_.png">
                    <p class="mt-4 mb-3 heading_size">pickup from item\'s location </p>
                    </div>';
          /*
          echo '<span class="font-weight-bold how-can-this-text">' . "how can this item be received" . '</span>';
          echo "<br>";
          echo "<br>";
          echo '<span class="font-weight-bold mb-3 ml-3">' . "pickup from item's location <br/>" . '</span>';
          echo "<br>";
          echo "<br>"; */
          $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);


          foreach ($unserialized as $key => $value) {
              echo '
                    <div class="dates_timings_items_availability">
                    <div class="items_availability_weekdays">' . strtolower(date('l', strtotime($key))) . ':</div>
                    <div class="items_availability_time"><span>' . $value['start'] . '</span></div>
                    <div class="delimiter">to</div>
                    <div class="items_availability_time"><span>' . $value['end'] . '</span></div>
                    </div>';
          }
    ?>
     </div>
   </div>
 <?php } ?>
   <!-- how can this item be received + PICKUP from item's location (FINISH) -->
   <!--DELIVER to my location (START)-->
   <?php
     $serialized = '';
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->item_logistic); $i++) {
         if (strcmp($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_type, "delivery") == 0) {
             $serialized .= strtolower($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_times);
         }
     }
     if ($serialized != '') {
  ?>
   <div class="deliver-to-my-location">
      <div class="timings">
        <?php
              echo '<div class="icons_text">
                      <img src="/images/rsz_deliveryicon__1_.png">
                      <p class="mt-4 heading_size mb-3" style="width:100%;">deliver to my location </p>
                      </div>';
              /*
              echo "<br>";
              echo "<br>";
              echo '<span class="font-weight-bold mb-3 ml-3">' . "deliver to my location <br/>" . '</span>';
              echo "<br>";
              echo "<br>"; */
              $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);

              foreach ($unserialized as $key => $value) {
                  echo '
                      <div class="dates_timings_items_availability">
                      <div class="items_availability_weekdays">' . strtolower(date('l', strtotime($key))) . ':</div>
                      <div class="items_availability_time"><span>' . date('g:i a', strtotime($value['start'])) . '</span></div>
                      <div class="delimiter">to</div>
                      <div class="items_availability_time"><span>' . date('g:i a', strtotime($value['end'])) . '</span></div>
                      </div>';
              }

        ?>
     </div>
   </div>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Please let me know if you bump into any issues with the code above.

*EDIT*:

```
.received {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    /* -webkit-box-pack: center; */
    /* -ms-flex-pack: center; */
    /* justify-content: center; */
}
```

Comment out the bottom 3 styles like I have above on the `.received` selector class.

Comment: I push your changes in my code. Click on [handoff](https://search.ruckify.com/item/6dc00670-e3fc-11e7-beeb-27568a0e8e4b) section here. At this moment after pushing your changes, when the left div is empty then the right div is coming at the center. Is there any way we can push **right div** towards the left when **left div is empty** ?

Comment: I think we need to do some styling now, not sure. If you want I can send the complete hand off code.

Comment: @john you're correct its now just styling it to be how you want it. I'm updating my answer with a CSS code to prevent it from becoming centred itself.

Comment: I have accepted your answer and awarded the bounty. I have one quick question related to the website related to the [particular url](https://search.ruckify.com/item/a8d8c0d0-63cd-11e8-b948-07273ed1d744). 
The footer content (having big U logo) at the bottom doesn't have complete padding but if you check similar urls [1](https://search.ruckify.com/item/6dc00670-e3fc-11e7-beeb-27568a0e8e4b) and [2](https://search.ruckify.com/item/6e7978e0-e3fc-11e7-84b1-69d66c3b4498) the footer doesn't have any padding.

Comment: I am not sure why is this happening. Spent almost 3 hours in figuring out that. The page for every url has the same html/php code but this [particular url](https://search.ruckify.com/item/a8d8c0d0-63cd-11e8-b948-07273ed1d744) is behaving differently

Comment: @john, there seems to be a missing closing `</div>` for the `<div class="row border-bottom rules_insurance_delivery">`. You'd have to carefully look at that div in the PHP code and determine where it's required to be, or you could guess and check. From an outside perspective, I'd say it should be situated somewhere after my code above.

Comment: Why other urls don't have that missing div ? Why only in that particular url ?

Comment: I checked now, there is no missing div. All divs are ok.

Comment: Check the url with no. [1](https://search.ruckify.com/item/6dc00670-e3fc-11e7-beeb-27568a0e8e4b) and [2](https://search.ruckify.com/item/6e7978e0-e3fc-11e7-84b1-69d66c3b4498) which I sent you above. They are all fine. I am just thinking why only this [particular url](https://search.ruckify.com/item/a8d8c0d0-63cd-11e8-b948-07273ed1d744)

Comment: This is the complete [code](http://codepad.org/XBcLdngc) Can you let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: @john, okay, I think you misunderstood me. What I was trying to say was your compiled code was missing elements. This means it is likely that your `if` statements either has an opening tag outside the `if` and the closing in the `if` (which was the case) or a opening tag inside the `if` and a closing outside the `if`. I've uploaded the changes here: http://codepad.org/QYYtaIg0. You will notice it was roughly 2-3 lines changed.

Comment: hi lachie, how are you ? Its been a while I have asked question from you. I have one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959641/how-to-sort-on-the-basis-of-customer-name-in-sql-using-case-statements) from sql. Let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 3):

The most [`kiss`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution here is to change your `php` and avoid rendering a blank `html` element. Why would you add something if it doesn't do anything, right?

```
<div class="received">

   <?php 
        echo $data['item'];

          $serialized = '';
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->item_logistic); $i++) {
          if(strcmp($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_type, "location_pickup") == 0)
          {
          $serialized .= strtolower($data['item']->item_logistic[$i]->logistics_times);
          }
          }
          if($serialized != '')
          {
          echo
          '

          <!- conditional display ->

          <div class="pickup-from-items-location">
          <div class="timings">

          <!- conditional display ->

          <div class="icons_text">


          ...
```

Comment: Did you read my problem statement ? It will answer your question.

Comment: When the serialize string is empty, it will not enter the left and right div. Thats the logic I am using. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: @john that was a rhetorical question. I'm not asking anything, I'm saying - don't render `html` if it's empty, then you won't have to work around that with `js` or `css`.

Comment: I push @Lachie changes in my code. Click on handoff section [here](https://search.ruckify.com/item/a8d8c0d0-63cd-11e8-b948-07273ed1d744). At this moment after pushing his changes, when the `left div is empty` then the `right div is coming at the center`. Is there any way we can push `right div towards the left` when `left div is empty` ?

Comment: Change `justify-content: left;` on `.received` and remove `margin-left` from `.deliver-to-my-location`. Set `margin-right` only on the column that gets hidden. This way when the column is shown it will push the other one out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the divs is there and even if one is empty both will keep centered side by side so you can just hide the empty div try this:

```
<div class="received<?= (count($data['item']->logistic_out) == 0) ? " align-left":'' ?>">
<div class="pickup-from-items-location" class="<?= (count($data['item']->logistic_out) == 0) ? "invisible":'' ?>">
<div class="deliver-to-my-location" class="<?= (count($data['item']->logistic_out) == 0) ? "invisible":'' ?>">


.pickup-from-items-location 
{
margin-right: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
display: block;
}

.deliver-to-my-location 
{
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
display: block;
}

.invisible {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}

.align-left {
  -webkit-box-pack: left;
  -ms-flex-pack: left;
  justify-content: left;
}
```

Comment: I have tried with the above code. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: here is the live [website](https://search.ruckify.com/item/a8d8c0d0-63cd-11e8-b948-07273ed1d744) Click on handoff.

Comment: On hand off section, when the left section is empty, I want the right to come at the center and vice versa. And when the right section is empty, I want the left to come at the center and vice versa

Comment: Are you around ? I have made slight changes in the live website. The code which i am using is not the real one.

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: @john can you elaborate more as the code i suggest is to hide the main in case no data to render it so it should work

Comment: Can you check the website which I have sent ? It’s the same code which I have sent with few minor changes. so when left div is empty right div should move towards the left.

Comment: ok i got you, do the same with my answer above to hide the empty div then if the parent div "received" add this class conditionally if one of 2 divs are empty

.align_left{
-webkit-box-pack: left;
-ms-flex-pack: left;
justify-content: left;
}

Comment: This way you will hide the empty one and adjust the parent div to align its content to the right

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question that well but I'm guessing you are using a submit button click for submit , in which case why not use JavaScript?

HTML

JavaScript

```
   <script>
     function myFunction() {

        if (document.getElementById('left')=="") {
            document.getElementById('left').style.display = "none";
        } 
         document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
     }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set `display: none` on the `.pickup-from-items-location` when it is empty and control the gap between `.pickup-from-items-location` and `.deliver-to-my-location` using `space-between` so that `.deliver-to-my-location` moves left when `.pickup-from-items-location` is hidden.

I have created a sample below by stripping out the php code to make things simple and made the following changes to demonstrate how this will work. Hope it helps.

1. CSS: Changed the value of `justify-content:` to `space-between` for `.received`
2. CSS: Removed `margin-right` and `margin-left` from `.pickup-from-items-location` and `.deliver-to-my-location` respectively so that the spacing between them is controlled by the value set in point 1 above.
3. CSS: Added a new class style called `togglePFIL` that can be used to toggle the display of `.pickup-from-items-location` on and off.
4. JS: Created a new function `togglePFIL()` that can be used to toggle the display of `.pickup-from-items-location` on and off. You will need to call this function from your php code. The button is used just to demonstrate the use of the function.

NOTE: The quality of the JS code is not production-ready. You will need to rewrite it to fit your particular case. The sample code is used only to demonstrate how the display of the 2 div's can be controlled.

```js
function togglePFIL() {
  const pfil = document.getElementsByClassName('pickup-from-items-location')[0];
  pfil.classList.toggle('togglePFIL');
}
```

```css
.received {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*center;*/
}

.pickup-from-items-location {
  /*margin-right: 100px;*/
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.togglePFIL {
  display: none;
}

.deliver-to-my-location {
  /*margin-left: 100px;*/
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="received">
  <div class="pickup-from-items-location">
    PICKUP FROM ITEMS LOCATION
    <div class="timings">
      PFIL TIMINGS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="deliver-to-my-location">
    DELIVER TO MY LOCATION
    <div class="timings">
      DTML TIMINGS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <button onclick="togglePFIL()">Toggle PFIL</button>
```

Comment: Based on one of the comments you made below and looking at the link to your website, a value of "space-around" may be more appropriate than "space-between" in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering what changes I should make in the css code above or JS/Jquery code I need to add so that when left div is empty on run time, right div should move towards the left.

Since you want **runtime** solution, I'll skip PHP tuning and come to JS and CSS.

---

### Short answer:

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("pickup-from-items-location");
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var timing = c[i].children[0]
    if (timing.innerText == "") {
        c[i].style.display = "none";
        c[i].parentNode.style.justifyContent = 'left';
        c[i].parentNode.children[1].style.marginLeft = 0;
    }
}

c = document.getElementsByClassName("pickup-from-my-location");
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var timing = c[i].children[0]
    if (timing.innerText == "") {
        c[i].style.display = "none";
        c[i].parentNode.style.justifyContent = 'left';
        c[i].parentNode.children[0].style.marginRight = 0;
    }
}
```

You can validate this code easily. Go to [live-site](https://search.ruckify.com/item/a8d8c0d0-63cd-11e8-b948-07273ed1d744) and put this code to console and run.

---

### Explanation

You used `flex` on the container. So, if we add `display:none` to one of the children, other one will have the whole area. And after that add `justify-content:left` to align one element to left.

In your [live-site](https://search.ruckify.com/item/a8d8c0d0-63cd-11e8-b948-07273ed1d744), i see empty child just have

```
<div class="pickup-from-items-location" id="pickup_from_items_location">
    <div class="timings">
    </div>
</div>
```

After addition we'll have:

```
<div class="pickup-from-items-location" id="pickup_from_items_location" style="display:none">
```

To be clear, the thing we have to do is to check is there any `<div class="timings">` with empty content, and if there is, add `display:none` to its parent.

To determine if there is such a child, we can use that JS code;

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("pickup-from-items-location");
```

Since it's a list rather than just one element, we have to iterate on each element in,

```
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
```

After that, we can access `<div class="timings">` via

```
var timing = c[i].children[0]
```

We can check its content with

```
if (timing.innerText == "")
```

To add `display:block`to empty child:

```
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var timing = c[i].children[0]
    if (timing.innerText == "") {
        c[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

After that, we need to align element to left:

```
c[i].parentNode.style.justifyContent = 'left';
```

This is for right element. To handle other side, you have to repeat above code with this

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("pickup-from-my-location");
```

---

But, you have another problem with CSS. Every child of flexbox have margin-left or margin-right. This leads to asymmetric positioning when other child removed. There is one fix I see with JS:

After addition the `display:none` attribute, you can remove margin-left/right from successor child. To access successors (left and right childs with content):

```
c[i].parentNode.children[1].style.marginLeft = 0
```

and other one

```
c[i].parentNode.children[0].style.marginRight = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If css is developed in that manner so that if hide left div than right div will go left than this will work fine.

if no data in left div, add class hide so that from css it will hide and right dive will go automatically left.

if this is not the case please reply so that i will provide other answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.hide{
    display: none;
}

.show{
    display: block;
}

</style>
<body>

    <div class="received">
        <div class="pickup-from-items-location **<?=count($data['item']->item_logistic?'show':'hide'?>**">
            <div class="timings">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="deliver-to-my-location">
            <div class="timings">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with float-left and float-right. As your code runs and reaches the block where you want to check if its empty, append the class float-left or float right.

In your case your container , assuming its empty
would be  and div class="deliver-to-my-location float-left">

```
 .float-left{
    float:left !important;
  }
 .float-right{
    float:right !important;
  }
```

In your PHP code

```
   //$empty  is a variable that stores the state of empty or non-empty

   if($empty){
     echo "<div class=\"pickup-from-items-location float-right\">";
   }else{
      echo "<div class=\"pickup-from-items-location\">";
   }

  if(!$empty){
    echo "<div class=\"deliver-to-my-location\">";
  }else{
    echo "<div class=\"deliver-to-my-location float-left\">";
  }
```

There are cleaner ways to this with vanilla JS or jquery. I am not very sure about the below solution

```
   ///jquery
   //Check if the div is empty


   if ('.pickup-from-items-location').is(':empty')){
       //append the class to float to right
       $(".deliver-to-my-location").addClass("float-right");
       $(".pickup-from-items-location").addClass("float-left");
   }
```

PS : Remove/trim any whitespace before checking of empty