# How to sort on a column in Lexicographical order in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am working on the website in which I want to sort everything on the basis of **customer_name (which is the 1st column from the table)**..

Below is my query in php code I have:

```
.....
.....
$y = isset($filters['items']['yaxis']) ? $filters['items']['yaxis'] : null;
$x = isset($filters['items']['xaxis']) ? $filters['items']['xaxis'] : null;

switch ($y) {
    case 'customer_name':
        $query->order( columns: $y . ' ' . (strtoupper($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'));    
        break;
}
```

**Problem Statement**:

I am wondering what changes I should make in the SQL Query above so that it sorts everything on the basis of `customer_name` only but sorting should follow the logic as mentioned below:

```
let arr = [
  '1 Hello',
  '2 Hello',
  '3 Hello',
  '4 Hello',
  ';1',
  'z',
  '%1',
  '110 Hello',
  '100 Hello',
  'a',
  'Z',
  '00',
  '21 Hello',
  '9  Hello',
  '13 Hello',
  '10000 Hello',
  '0 Hello',
  'A'
  ];


arr.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {
    numeric: true
  })
} ).forEach( ml => { console.log(ml) });
```

The above Javascript is printing the following o/p:

```
;1
%1
00
0 Hello
1 Hello
2 Hello
3 Hello
4 Hello
9  Hello
13 Hello
21 Hello
100 Hello
110 Hello
10000 Hello
a
A
z
Z
=> undefined
```

So I want to sort all the data on `customer_name` in my above php file but in Lexicographical order just like my above javascript is doing.

Comment: Is there a upper limit to number of characters in the string ?

Comment: There is no upper limits I  guess as of now.

Comment: Need information about what is the character set and collation defined on the column. If you can setup a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ , I can give it a try.